# Calcular promedio de un valor con campo fecha

Tags: python, google-colab, regresión-lineal

Estoy intentando calcular el promedio de plazas disponible de parking con respecto a una fecha sin embargo tengo varios datos para una misma fecha, debido a que el formato fecha esta en horas, minutos etc

[image: lectura de datos]

```
with open('Antigone.json', 'r') as datafile:
data = json.load(datafile)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

realice el cambio del campo update_date a datatime

```
X['update_date'] = [datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z").strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').split (' ') [0] 
         for d in df['update_date']
        ]
  X.head()


 X['update_date']=pd.to_datetime(df['update_date'])
```

ahora debo agrupar por fecha el promedio de 'nb_places_libres'
he tratado de realizar lo siguiente
crear una nueva columna 'promedio' pero no hace nada, la idea es dejar una sola linea con el promedio por dia, agradezco cualquier ayuda

```
promedio = df.groupby("update_date") ['nb_places_libres'].mean()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

**Nota:** Como no incluiste tus datos cree un `dataframe` genérico para mostrar la solución.

Puedes utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) para calcular el promedio y [`pandas.Series.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) para obtener las fechas.

Utilizando el siguiente `dataframe` en el archivo "sample2.csv":

```
                update_date  nb_places_libres
0 2022-08-05 18:17:57+00:00               144
1 2022-08-05 18:59:57+00:00               145
2 2022-08-05 18:59:57+00:00               145
3 2022-08-05 19:02:52+00:00               145
4 2022-08-17 18:17:57+00:00               117
5 2022-08-17 18:59:57+00:00               120
6 2022-08-17 18:59:57+00:00               121
7 2022-08-17 19:02:52+00:00               121
```

Primero nos aseguramos que la columna `update_date` sea de tipo `datetime64`, utilizamos el argumento `infer_datetime_format` para intentar "adivinar" (Inferir) el formato de fecha que se está usando en el archivo:

```
df['update_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['update_date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Y por último agrupamos por fecha y obtenemos el promedio

```
df_mean = df.groupby(df['update_date'].dt.date).mean()
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv')
df['update_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['update_date'], infer_datetime_format=True)

df_mean = df.groupby(df['update_date'].dt.date).mean()
print(df_mean)
```

Esto devuelve el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
             nb_places_libres
update_date                  
2022-08-05             144.75
2022-08-17             119.75
```

Comment: muchas gracias fue de gran ayuda